# Impossible to set my joomla site timezone to Pacific/Tahiti (hosted in UTC)

Tags: php, .htaccess-configuration, server, hosting

I have exactely the same issue like in this [post](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16274/question-about-server-timezones-and-j3-5-extentions/21273#21273).

For a Joomla site online booking (Joomla + Yootheme + Vik Appointment) I need Pacific/Tahiti default timezone and I still have UTC despite all my efforts. I am stuck.

- I put into Vik Appointments extension ini files : date_default_timezone_set("Pacific/Tahiti");
- Joomla configuration server is set at : Pacific/Tahiti
- My hosting provider set php.ini with : php_admin_value[date.timezone] = Pacific/Tahiti (I asked for : date.timezone = "Pacific/Tahiti" but he changes it, I guess he has some reasons, but it told me he can not guarantee as this parameter is only global)
- My .htaccess is set with : SetEnv TZ Pacific/Tahiti

but php info still says I am in UTC, and the site make erratic booking dates and times :-( at this point I really don't see why I am still stuck!

How and where should I put the code give on the [post](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16274/question-about-server-timezones-and-j3-5-extentions/21273#21273) for .htaccess? suPHP_ConfigPath /home3/username_here order allow,deny deny from all

Thank you in advance for help, much apreciated

Regards
Yannick

Comment: Did you try `php_value date.timezone "Pacific/Tahiti"` in `.htaccess` as per https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/16278/120 ?

Answer (score 1):

The following only works if your hosting provider allows own php.ini files:

1) Go to Joomla root.
2) create you own php.ini (just create an empty txt-file and change the extension to "ini")

3) Add

```
date.timezone = Pacific/Tahiti
```

to the php.ini

4) Upload to the Joomla root

5) (optional, if needed by your server to work) Add this to the end of your htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /YOUR ABSOLUTE PATH TO THE JOOMLA ROOT HERE
<Files php.ini>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
</IfModule>
```

This could take some minutes to take effect.

To get your absolute path, just upload a test.php file into your Joomla root:

```
<?php
echo __DIR__; // or echo realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
```